# Angular 6, Cannot import component into routing.module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7

This is my file structure:

[image: Image of Folder Structure...]

My app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SearchFormComponent } from './components/search-form/search-form.component';
import { QueryDisplayComponent } from './components/query-display/query-display.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchFormComponent,
    QueryDisplayComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  exports:[],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

'' app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Places Search
  </h1>
</div>


<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

the component im trying to display when the route is hit

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
// import { Place } from '../../place'
import { GetReqPlaces } from '../../services/get-req-places.service'
import { Router } from '@angular/router'


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-form',
  templateUrl: './search-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-form.component.css']
})
export class SearchFormComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private getPlaces: GetReqPlaces, private router: Router) { }

  westLong: number;
  eastLong: number;
  northLat: number;
  southLat: number;

  // log(x){console.log(x)}
  onSubmit(form){

  this.westLong = form.value.wLong; // 
  this.eastLong = form.value.eLong; // 
  this.northLat = form.value.nLat; // 
  this.southLat = form.value.sLat; // 
    console.log(this.getPlaces.getPlaces(this.westLong,this.southLat,this.eastLong,this.northLat))
  }

}
```

'' routing module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent} from './app.component'
import { SearchFormComponent} from '../components/search-form.component'


const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'search', component: SearchFormComponent },


];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

the error code is as follows in VScode:

"message": "Cannot find module '../components/search-form.component'."

and

"ERROR in src/app/app-routing.module.ts(4,36): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../components/search-form.component'."

in the angular cli when i try to serve the app.

Im kind of at my wits end, im able to import AppComponent, but why is router module not recognizing the SearchFormComponent? 4 hours into this i feel like its at the tip of my fingers but I feel like i dug myself into a black hole. Thank you for your help and patience, new to Angular and loving it... despite what this post may represent haha. I'd love to get over this bump and start working on the backend.

Comment: Please share your file structure in some format

Comment: since routing module is in the same folder of app module u can import like this `import { SearchFormComponent } from './components/search-form/search-form.component';`

Comment: I was not allowed by StackOverflow. My account is not credible enough to post images yet.

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan yes thank you, it was not just that but also i missed a folder in the path, coding an entire day and not seeing the sun causes lapses in short-term memory... thank you to everyone who jumped to my help despite how simple this problem turned out to be, much love!

Answer (score 1):

try

`import { SearchFormComponent} from './components/search-form.component'`

Not `../` , it's `./` as components folder & routing file is under same level of folder structure

Comment: Also './components/search-form/search-form.component' i forgot the .../search-form/... file path, thanks Ritwick!

Comment: That worked ? Feel free to accept/upvote answer if that worked

Comment: had to give it to @N.HariHaraSudhan for being there first, i was banging my head reading the routing docs over and over, at least i learned things for the future haha :D, gave ya an upvote though!

Answer (score 1):

Since routing module is in the same folder of app module u can import like this

> import { SearchFormComponent } from './components/search-form/search-form.component'